# Invalid CSS after "...kground-color: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@gray-lightest;"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

Hello I am learning rails, I am suddenly getting this error message in my new project,

Invalid CSS after "...kground-color: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@gray-lightest;"

here is my Application.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 */


 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
 @import "home.scss"
```

then I have a home.scss

```
 @gray-lightest: lighten(#000, 97.25%);

 body {
     background-color: @gray-lightest;
 }
```

and I have in my gemfile

```
gem 'sass-rails',  '5.0.6'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.7'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.3.1'
gem 'haml-rails'
```

I have seen already the sass solutions but i want to use scss or css. I've tried updating the bundler and all the gems. My other projects is doing fine. What could i have done wrong this time? why am i getting this error? is the .scss extension not working? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCSS support this syntax to set variable:

```
$gray-lightest: lighten(#000, 97.25%);

body {
     background-color: $gray-lightest;
}
```